# JScrollpane not scrolling when collapsible panels are added

Tags: java, swing

I have added some collapsible panels to my JScrollpane. When they are extended, the JScrollpane is not allowing me to scroll. Below is the code I'm using.

```
 JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(makeContentForPropertiesWindow());
    propertiesTabDoc.add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

The makeContentForPropertiesWindow method populates the collapsible panels. I've used GridLAyout there. I've also tried FlowLayout and BorderLAyout as well. All result in the same output. Currently below is how it looks.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Why is it not allowing me to scroll though the vertical area is full? Please advice.

Comment: `I've used GridLAyout there.` - that doesn't make any sense. Whenever you collapse a panel, I'm sure you don't want the empty space to be displayed. The preferred size of the panel must be able to grow/shrink as the state of each collapsing panel is changed. If the scrollbars don't appear you have a problem with the layout manager.

Comment: Have you created those collapsable panels yourself, or are you using some sort of library? What happens, when you put normal panels inside the scrollbar?